# PHP LARAVEL ERROR: no pages are found except index page in Laravel deployed on LAMP Stack on Ubuntu 16 OS

Tags: 16.04, server, php, php7, laravel

Running Ubuntu 16 server image on Google Compute Engine. My very first time to touch Ubuntu. I have installed Laravel via `composer` and done everything properly, but my webiste is only opening the home page, everything else is showing this error:

```
404 not found
```

You can check the website here: `http://35.227.60.17`
Every button is redirected in routes, they are just the routes.

1. I have set my virtual host and disabled the `000-default.conf` file and it's still the same.
2. I have test it locally on XAMPP server (Windows). it's fine.
3. Even database migrations are running.
4. I have installed all dependencies via `composer`.
5. I have `php` 5.6, 7.0, 7.1, 7.2 installed in my server along with all extensions for each version.

Here is my `routes/web.php`:

```
App\Post
Route::get('/','PagesControllers@index');
Route::get('/about','PagesControllers@about');
Route::get('/services','PagesControllers@services');
Route::resource('posts','PostsController');
// writing a route for PostController other than resources
//and using App\Post for Post model...
Route:: get('/mytestroute', function()
{
$posts= Post::paginate(1);
return view('mytestroute')->with('posts', $posts);
});
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Try running this in the terminal

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

And then add to your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-defaults.conf` inside **VirtualHost** tag another tag:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Replace `/var/www/html` with whatever your document root is. Finally restart apache

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

And you should be good to go!

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CatEn5IAlo